# Pass multiple parameters in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, vs-web-site-project

```
class Article(models.Model):
      Title     = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
      writing       = models.TextField()
      category  = models.CharField(max_length = 225)
      published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      updated       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
      slug      = models.SlugField(blank=True, editable=False)

      def save(self):
         self.slug = slugify(self.Title)
         super().save()

      def get_absolute_url(self):
         url_slug = {'slug':self.slug}
         return reverse('artikel:ArticleDetail', kwargs = url_slug)

      def __str__(self):
         return "{}.{}".format(self.id, self.Title)
```

i want to build a simple website using django where it could post some articles by form. The problem is how could i post multiple category in one article ? this is form.py below.

```
from .models import Article
from django.forms import ModelForm 

class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = Article
      fields = [
        'title',
        'writing',
        'category',
       ]
```

Comment: You should consider using a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) instead of a `CharField` for your category field

Answer (score 0):

You can a [**`ManyToManyField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) to link your post to multiple categories, for example:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    writing = models.TextField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('artikel:ArticleDetail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

      def __str__(self):
         return '{}.{}'.format(self.id, self.title)
```

That being said, there already are some packages for this. [**`django-taggit`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/jazzband/django-taggit) for example, you can install this with:

```
pip3 install django-taggit
```

and include `'taggit'` to the [**`INSTALLED_APPS`** list [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#installed-apps):

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # …,
    'taggit',
    # …
]
```

Then in your models, you can add a `TaggableManager` to the model:

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    writing = models.TextField()
    categories = TaggableManager()
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('artikel:ArticleDetail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

      def __str__(self):
         return '{}.{}'.format(self.id, self.title)
```

As the documentation specifies, it comes with a [*form field*](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html) that allows one to write space-separated and comma-separated tags.

Comment: how can i apply it in template.html and views.py ?

Comment: If you use a `ModelForm` in your view, then it will render this with the specific form field in the template.

Comment: No, i mean how can we create relatable categories and display it in website, i've done  about ModelForm

Comment: @IchwanulMukminAbbas: normally the `TaggableManager` creates `Tag` objects based on the names entered.